# How to know the files created by a certain software?

Tags: linux, command-line, debian

How to know the files created by a certain software?
Under Linux when I install a software it will create files and directories.
How can I know which ones?

For example if I install `vsftpd` , this tool will create

```
/usr/sbin/vsftpd
/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf 
...
```

Is there any command line or tool just made to know that?

Comment: Do you want to find all files created by a certain program, or identify the source program for a specific file, or are you talking about finding the configuration files created when installing a specific program, or was that meant as an example of a file being created, or a list of all files installed as part of a programs installation, or ...  Once you define what it is you want, are you looking for a method to get it (probably on-topic), or a software recommendation (off-topic)?

Comment: You are asking 2 different questions: (A)  _"How can I understand which files install a package"_.  (B) _"Which program can create/manage file as the XYZ one?"_ What do you really want to know? Please choose one and [edit] your post or title. Ps> Welcome on `[}`super __user__.

Comment: You can know both... but those are different questions (that you can do separately, if you don't find just done). For example do you want to know what is happening or what is happened? This too make A difference. ( I mean do you want to know which files is creating / modifying a running process, what to do to know if a process did, what to do before to know after what a process did, what to do before to know meantime...). In this site you should write a specific question so that other users can write a short, quick, answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Debian based operating systems just type in the terminal:

```
dpkg -L <software>
```

For red-hat based operating systems

```
rpm -ql <software>
```

Both will output all the files associated with the software.
For example:

```
shell>#rpm -ql httpd

/etc/httpd
/etc/httpd/conf
/etc/httpd/conf.d
/etc/httpd/conf.d/README
/etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf

...  (below ) ...

/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_info.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so

... ( around 400 lines below ) ...

/usr/share/man/man8/suexec.8.gz
/var/cache/httpd
/var/cache/httpd/proxy
/var/lib/dav
/var/log/httpd
/var/www
/var/www/cgi-bin
/var/www/html
```

.

Comment: The OP mentions `debian` in the tags; `rpm` is a command for RedHat, it does not exist on Debian.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Thanks mate. I have edited my answer for both types of kernels.

Comment: I think you mean 'distributions' instead of 'kernels'.

Answer (score 2):

## You can see the modification of the directories/files on your filesystem at *different levels*.

If you want to see which files an official package **install**s, you can follow the answers of  MariusMatutiae or Rishabh Soni and use `dpkg`.
IMHO `apt-file` is **more cosy** then `dpkg` (e.g. `apt-file list vsftpd`).

Generally speaking, if you want **to be sure** that is a specific program and not another to create a file, you have to **monitor that program**. At the same way if you want to check who is modifying a file you have to **monitor that file**. This is even more true with program that don't belong to the official packages of  a Linux distribution.

To ***"monitor meanwhile*" a process** that is creating or modifying files on your filesystem you can use [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) or [FAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Alteration_Monitor), *extensions* of the kernel created and optimized for this purpose.
If you want to monitor only what is created/accessed **by a process** you can use [lsof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof)

```
lsof -n -p `pidof your_app`   # If you know the PID of your software
./Install.sh & lsof -n -p $!  # Here it takes the last program in background
```

On another level, you can give a look to [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace), able to **monitor all the system-calls** of a process, which includes all file access. It is a powerful tool even if with an output not so clean.

You can use [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) if you want to see the files **created or modified in a temporal window**, e.g. after that you have installed the program or when you presume or you know that the program was running.
For example, you can search for all the files (and not directories) created in the last 5 minutes *somewhere down* starting from the present directory with

```
find . -type f -mmin 5 -print
```

but changing the options you can search for the files, directories, symbolic and hard links ... Of course this method uses more CPU and disk accesses then the dedicated kernel patches reported above, but if you have to search for it only one time this is a better solution, especially if you do not start to search from the root `/`.

Last but not least you can try to **identify a file type** with the command `file`, e.g. `file MyScript.sh`, with the list of signature (or [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) ), or with the [List of filename extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions). Once you know the filetype you can guess the program that have created or modified a file among the ones you have installed on that computer... and start to monitor them.

Comment: Ps> To identify a file type you can try with the command `file`. E.g. `file myfile`, with the list of signature (or [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) ), or with the [file extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions). Once you know the filetype you can guess the program that should create or modify it.